# Is there a Vivitar 273 flash power regulation hack?

Tags: flash, diy, manual-flash

[I found this post about a hack](http://www.photomacrography.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=55625) to regulate the power of an old Vivitar 283 flash.

As I own two unmodified Vivitar 273 flashes, I wonder whether there is a similar hack to modify this model as well to be able to regulate the flash light output power?

Comment: Clarification: Are you wanting to regulate the light output power of the flash or the trigger voltage?

Comment: The light output power. For lowering the trigger voltage I found some instructions already.